# I can’t access any Google-related websites

Tags: google-chrome, microsoft-edge

When I try to go onto Google or [YouTube](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YouTube), this message always pops up:

> "Hmmm… can't reach this page 
> Check if there is a typo in [www.google.com](http://www.google.com). 
> DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN"

I even checked them in my other browser. I was using [Edge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Edge) and [Chrome](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Chrome). This problem was going on for an hour earlier, but then it stopped and it went back to normal for a few hours. But now the problem is going on again. What’s wrong and how can I stop it from happening?

Comment: Before when it happened, I just went onto bing to search my stuff up, but now bing has the same problem

Comment: No idea... are you using a VPN or other network-related software/hardware? Also, any country related issues?

Comment: @Phix Im not using a vpn, well if i was, it wasn't for the entire computer, it was only an extension for chrome and i had many different users and only one of them was using a VPN. And i don't know of any country related issues.

Answer (score 0):

The `DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN` error may occur due to the misconfiguration or due to the problem with the DNS.

Several ways are available that might help you fix this issue.

1. Disable [VPN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_private_network) or antivirus software temporarily.
2. Restart the computer.
3. If possible for you then reset the **flags** for the **Chrome** and **Edge** browsers.

The **flags** menu allows you to enable or disable experimental features. In the Edge browser, you can type `edge://flags/` in the address bar and press the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key. In the Chrome browser, you can type `chrome://flags/` in the address bar and press the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key. Then you can click the <kbd>Reset all</kbd> button to reset flags.

4. Check the [*hosts* file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_(file)) and make sure that it does not contain the site address that you want to visit.

On a Windows machine, the *hosts* file is located under *C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc*.

On a [Mac](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Macintosh) machine, try to run the `sudo nano /private/etc/hosts` command in a terminal to access the *hosts* file.

**If the issue persists after trying the above options then you may try these advanced options.**

5. If possible for you then try to **release and renew the IP address**.

On a Windows machine, launch the command prompt and run `ipconfig /release` command to release the current IP address. Then after running the `ipconfig /flushdns` command to flush **local DNS cache**. After that run the  `ipconfig /renew` command to renew the IP address.

On a Mac machine, go to **System Preferences**, click on the network icon, and then click “Advanced.” Click the *TCP/IP* tab, and then click on the “Renew DHCP” button.

To clear the **local DNS cache** on Mac, run `dscacheutil -flushcache` command in terminal.

6. If possible for you then try to restart **DNS Client Service** on the Windows machine. Launch the command prompt and run the `net stop dnscache` command. After that run the `net start dnscache` command.

You can test the above suggestions and see whether it fix this issue.

Comment: Okay thanks! Ill try them out. And what are flags in the third method and also, I'm on a mac.

Comment: @WolfyWolf33, I have updated my answer with the information related to the `flags` and I have added the steps for MAC OS. You can also try it. If you need more detailed information, I suggest you search `DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN` in your favorite search engine. It may help you to get additional information on this issue.

Comment: Thanks, i will do that, this problem comes up very often now. LIke i someetiems would spam reload and it would work after a minute.

Comment: You can share your test results and let us know whether it works or not.

Comment: 1 2 and 3 havent worked yet and I'm not sure what to do for 4. Like i ran that line in terminal and then like a thing popped up with like about host database and how localhost is used to configure the loopback interface and it shows my localhost, broadcasthost and another local host. And then at the bottom there's a bunch of keys i can press to go to other pages and a bunch of things.

Comment: I did number 5 and google seems to be working for now. It usually does work for a few minutes at moments. Ill keep it posted.

Comment: Okay, it just stopped working again, same error.

Comment: I did number 6 and its working again, duno if its coincidence or it fixed it, ill keep you posted

Comment: its really weird now. Sometimes it would work sometimes it wouldn't. Like my google and youtube was working on chrome, but bing isn't working on chrome. and on edge, only my google is working and nothing else is and its weird. Its really funky, its working on and off

Comment: Another thing you can try on MAC OS is to change the **DNS server address**. Go to `System Preferences-> Network`. Click the `Advanced` button then go to the `DNS` tab. Click on the `+` button. Enter `8.8.8.8`. Again click the `+` button and enter `8.8.4.4`. Click the `OK` button. Then again try to check for the issue.

Comment: Actually, my school doesnt allow me to do that. THey just say you cant touch any network things.

Comment: In that case, I suggest you contact the IT department of your school and inform them about this issue. They can help you to fix this issue. Thanks for your understanding.

Comment: I dont want to contact them though. They are really mean sometimes and always think us kids are doing random stuff to mess up our computers.

Comment: Now its just that i have to reload many times before it works

Comment: I still think that you should take help from the IT department instead of trying to fix the issue by yourself.

Comment: Hm...ill look into it then.

Comment: It worked for a month and now its not working again.

Comment: @Deepak-MSFT - can you take a look here? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67708223/unable-to-reach-www-google-com-on-mac

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I installed Cloudflare Warp VPN. Even though I didn't use it when I start my PC, it's services were still running in the background. The problem was solved by uninstalling it.