# Unable to reach www.google.com on mac

Tags: networking, dns

In the past 2 weeks I started having an issue w/ search on google.
I enter a search term in the search box or in the address line and chrome takes a long time until something happens.

At first it would say it couldn't reach the site and then immediately load the search results, but now it just says

> This site can’t be reachedCheck if there is a typo in [www.google.com](http://www.google.com).
> DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN

I tried searching in google from firefox and got the same behavior.
I pinged `google.com` in the terminal and the ping looked fine, but when I pinged `www.google.com` the ping timed out

```
~ % ping google.com
PING google.com (74.125.140.113): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 74.125.140.113: icmp_seq=0 ttl=107 time=69.498 ms
64 bytes from 74.125.140.113: icmp_seq=1 ttl=107 time=71.254 ms
64 bytes from 74.125.140.113: icmp_seq=2 ttl=107 time=69.944 ms
64 bytes from 74.125.140.113: icmp_seq=3 ttl=107 time=71.139 ms
^C
--- google.com ping statistics ---
4 packets transmitted, 4 packets received, 0.0% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max/stddev = 69.498/70.459/71.254/0.756 ms

~ % ping www.google.com
ping: cannot resolve www.google.com: Unknown host
```

tried restart of the mac and nothing changed

I tried following the suggestions here and it didn't work
https://stackoverflow.com/a/65695189/2482564

mac version:11.2.3

any ideas on how to move forward?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As it was explained to me by a colleague the problem comes from my ISP DNS server,

I had to change the DNS on the mac from the default DNS to 8.8.8.8

using `System Preferences-> Network`. Click the `Advanced` button then go to the `DNS tab`. Click on the `+` button. Enter `8.8.8.8`

it was explained in one of the comments here - https://stackoverflow.com/a/65695189/2482564

You can read a little about the google public dns - https://developers.google.com/speed/public-dns

Comment: Had to restart my mac after doing this